# Next.js 14 Draft Mode not working in an iframe(headless CMS preview)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, content-management-system, next.js13

I have tried using the [Draft Mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/draft-mode) in two of my projects which are built with combination of **Next.js 14** and Headless CMS(Storyblok, Crystalize). While the Draft Mode workes perfectly fine in a browser tab it doesn't work in any of the the CMS UI's preview(iframe). I have previous projects built with the **pages router** and the "Preview Mode"(same functionality as draft mode) in them works so it's nothing to do with the CMS's.

**Here's my setup:**

- Next.js 14.0.4
- [local-ssl-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-ssl-proxy)(the iframes require https)
- Chrome v121
- CMS: Storyblok or Crystalize
- Ubuntu 22.04.3

**Here's my `draft/route.ts`:**

```js
// route handler with secret and slug
import { draftMode } from 'next/headers';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { paths } from '@/constants/paths';

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  // Parse query string parameters
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
  const crystallizeSignature = searchParams.get('crystallizeSignature');
  const slug = searchParams.get('slug');

  // TODO: Check the secret and slug
  if (!crystallizeSignature || !slug) {
    return new Response('Invalid token', { status: 401 });
  }

  // Enable Draft Mode by setting the cookie
  draftMode().enable();

  // Redirect to the path from the fetched post and remove the prefix
  const slugWithoutPrefix = slug.replace(paths.crystallizeRoot, '');

  redirect(`${slugWithoutPrefix}`);
}
```

**Here's what i tried and didn't work:**

1. Updating Nextjs to latest version
2. Refered to this [GH issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49927). I have tried all the solutions/workarounds people suggested but none of them worked. Even checking if the cookie was correct in the response:[image]
3. Using Firefox
4. Setting a random cookie(e.g test-cookie=123455) to check if any cookie will be set at all and when i logged out all cookies the test-cookie was visible in the iframe